# How does player level and difficulty affect story mode gameplay?

Tags: destiny

A story mission might have several difficulties, e.g., normal level 14, hard level 18, hard level 20, impossible level 24. What actually changes across these difficulties? Enemy health? Player health? Enemy weapon power? Drops and in-map vehicles? Experience and glimmer gain? The only difference I can see from the settings is that there is a greater XP bonus for finishing on a higher difficulty, but I don't know what that entails. What are the differences between story difficulty levels?

This is also to ask how player level affects story mode gameplay. I heard someone say that every level difference added/removed 20% of difficulty, but I couldn't verify this anywhere else.